# User embedded timeline for Twitter

Tags: twitter

is it possible to refresh the User timeline's tweets automatically, without having to refresh the page / reload the Javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation:

> They load fast, scale with your traffic, and update in real-time.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's actually possible. we don't know which technology you want or what you're trying to do, but it's possible, even from the browser itself.